# How can i connect my websocket url to power bi to visualize live data

Tags: websocket, powerbi-datasource

I have a websocket url and i need to visualize its live data in power bi
But power bi says it cant support wss, so any one knows how to connect webscokets to power bi for live visualization using any powerbi connectors .

[It shows wss type is not supported](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oUJYX.png)

Comment: Have a look at [Real-time streaming in Power BI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/connect-data/service-real-time-streaming). You will need a service in the middle to push the data to the streaming dataset.

Comment: Hii Sam Nseir ,can u explain in detail, i have tried with real time streaming in power bi also